# How do I simplify $\log (1/\sqrt{1000})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I simplify $\log \left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}}\right)$?

What I have done so far:

1) Used the difference property of logarithms 
$$\log \left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}}\right) = \log(1) - \log(\sqrt{1000}) $$

2) Used the exponent rule for logarithm

$$\log (1) - \frac{1}{2}\log (1000) $$

I'm stuck at this point. Can someone explain why and what I must do to solve this equation?

Comment: $\log 10000 = \log 10^4 = 4 \log 10$

Comment: $\log 1=0$ and $\log 10000=4\log 10$ so this become $-2\log 10$.

Comment: Looks like you added an extra $0$ to the $1000$ after the step (2).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}}=10^{-\frac{3}{2}}\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad\log x^a=a\log x$$

Comment: Is the answwer -3/2log(10)?

Comment: @Prologue: Yes!

Comment: @Prologue Note that, in base 10, this simplifies to $-\frac{3}{2}.$ If you're in base $e$, then ignore the first part of this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

$\log_{10} \left( \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}} \right) = \log_{10} \left( \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{10^3}} \right) = \log_{10} \left( \displaystyle \frac{1}{{10^\frac{3}{{2}}}} \right) = \log_{10} \left( \displaystyle {{10^\frac{-3}{{2}}}} \right) = \displaystyle {{\frac{-3}{{2}}}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\log_{10} \left( \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}} \right) = \log_{10} \left( \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{10^3}} \right) = \log_{10} \left( \displaystyle \frac{1}{{10^\frac{3}{{2}}}} \right) = \log_{10} \left( \displaystyle {{10^\frac{-3}{{2}}}} \right) = \displaystyle {{\frac{-3}{{2}}}}$

Sorry I accidently erased an answer. Please restore. I submit mine as another.

Comment: Whose answer did you erase

Comment: MonK and maybe someone else

Comment: why would you erase dude?

Comment: because I might be in a rush when reading this question.